# Expression Blend 4.0 - Automatically reload edited files?

Tags: visual-studio, settings, expression-blend

I do a lot of editing between Blend and VS.  VS has a great option to "automatically reload changed files" so that I don't get prompted when I do some work in Blend and switch tools.  Going the other direction though I don't see an option for Blend to automatically load files when changed.  Is there a way to get rid of that dialog and always answer "yes?"

Comment: This would be great, same complaint here. :(

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at this time.  I can say that it has been requested by a lot of folks and the team is aware of the issue.

I know it's annoying, but you can stop gap the issue by closing the XAML file(s) in Blend before editing it(them) in Visual Studio.  The prompts only occur for open files, so when you return to Blend after working in VS for a time it won't prompt you. Then you can open the file and see the changes.  This works in both directions: since I typically do my XAML work in Blend I try to keep the XAML files closed in Visual Studio.